# rgb() with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb

In ggplot2, we have the option of setting colours by name or hex code. Is there any way to use rgb values in the same way? I searched the docs but the quick answer seems to be 'no'. (The reason I would like to use rgb is that I have some colours that I am going to use for some plots, and I have them all in rgb format. I can get the hex from places like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp), but it would be great if I could just enter the values straight into `ggplot()`.

Comment: What about the function [`rgb`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/rgb.html)?

Comment: `qplot(x=1, fill=I(rgb(0.1, 0.8, 0.5)))`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that function. Thanks, Axeman & bouncyball.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the function `rgb(r, g, b)` to convert fractional RGB values to hex:

```
rgb(0.1,0.2,0.3)
[1] "#1A334D"
```

If your values are based on 8-bit color (or any other limit), you can use the `maxColorValue` option to specify the maximum number:

```
rgb(207, 31, 46, maxColorValue = 255)
[1] "#CF1F2E"
```

Comment: Great. I used this directly in the plot function, but it needs the `maxColorValue` argument if you don't have your RGB colours in fractions: `scale_colour_manual(values = c(rgb(207, 31, 46, maxColorValue = 255)), "#ffda85"))`